# When is it reasonable to assume that the covariance matrix is positive definite?

Tags: correlation, cross-correlation

I know that any covariance matrix must be positive semi-definite, but are there any regimes where it is reasonable to assume that covariance matrix is postive definite.

I want to use this to be able to assume that the covariance matrix is invertible, and use the full matrix in a $\chi^{2}$-fit and the Backus-Gilbert method both requiring invertability/positive definite.

Answer (score 2):

You find a characterization of covariance matrices with zero eigen values here: [Sufficient and necessary conditions for zero eigenvalue of a correlation matrix](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/366558/sufficient-and-necessary-conditions-for-zero-eigenvalue-of-a-correlation-matrix)

So you have to ask yourself, whether linear dependencies among the variables may exist.